# How could I get the cubic of every element in a list?

Tags: python, list, lambda

I'm using an anonymous function and I need to cubic every element in the list by calling a normal function in an anonymous function. How could I fix my below error?

```
list1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def cubic(n):
    return n*n*n

f = list(map(cubic(n),list1))
```

Comment: I don't why people dislike this post. I'm learning and it is not a shame to learn.

Comment: What error? Why use `list(map())` instead of a list comprehension?

Comment: @AMC I just wanted to use an anonymous function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt was close. You want to pass the `cubic` function as a first-class value to `map`, rather than calling it, so replace `map(cubic(n),list1)` with `map(cubic,list1)`.

Comment: @ Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica Done dear.

Answer (score 1):

`map` will call `cubic` for you, so you shouldn't use parentheses with it. Try this:

```
list1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def cubic(n):
    return n**3

cubed_list = list(map(cubic, list1))
print(cubed_list)  # [8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729]
```

Alternatively, you could use a list comprehension.

```
list1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
cubed_list = [n**3 for n in list1]
print(cubed_list)  # [8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a list you do not even need to build a function to accomplish this. You can pass the list into a list comprehension:

```
[x**3 for x in list1]
```

This will return a list with each value in the prior list cubed! Super fantastic little deal. And if you need to apply a more complicated computation to each value you and use YOUR function in the comprehension:

```
[your_function(x) for x in list1]
```